# jQuery in Chrome Extension - Refused Inline Script eventhough Included properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to implement jQuery in my Chrome Extension in order to include the firebase.js in my background.js (which seems already weird), however chrome refuses to execute code from inside the jquery.js.

**background.js**

```
$.getScript('firebase.js', function()
{ 
// code depending on firebase.js, jquery is just needed here to include firebase.js
});
```

**popup.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
      <script src="jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
      <script src="firebase.js"></script>
      <script src="popup.js"></script>
      <script src="background.js"></script>
    </head>
  <body>
    //stuff happens
   </body>
</html>
```

**manifest.json**

```
 "content_scripts":[
    {
        "js":["jquery-3.0.0.min.js"],    
        "all_frames":true
}
],
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": true
  },
```

So for me it looks like it is included properly, however I am getting this, which is very weird, since it is inside the jquery library:

> jquery-3.0.0.min.js:2 Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy

Isn't there another method on how to include Firebase.js in the background.js? It makes no sense that it doesn't work there, it is included in my popup.html.

Comment: The rule of thumb is to never but ``script`` tags with inline javascript code insider your ``*.html`` files instead create a seperate ``.js`` files and include them using ``src="myscript.js"``

Comment: Where do you mean exactly? I'm aware that inline script doesn't get executed, I don't have any. The src's aren't inline script, right?

Comment: The problem is it doesn't want to execute inline script from inside the jquery.js, this doesn't make sense.

Comment: It just a remainder, and i think you have some inline js code somewhere in your code!

Comment: Perhaps because you are adding ``jquery-3.0.0.min.js`` to ``manifest.json`` ``background`` property!
Try to remove it from there and i think it may work

Comment: @hamism I removed it, same error.

Comment: Try also to remove ``jquery-3.0.0.min.js`` from ``content_scripts`` property of ``manifest.json`` as you are including jquery in your ``popup.hml``.

Comment: Same error, still.

Comment: ammm, may be you are calling js code from some html code for example 

``<button onclick="clicked()">click here</button>``

Comment: Well the error says it is inside the jquery.js. I checked, no inline script in my other files.

Comment: Where are you getting that error? In the background script or in the popup?

Comment: I think ``$.getScript('firebase.js', function()`` is the one causing problems!.


why don't put the code of ``firebase.js`` inside ``background.js`` ?

Comment: @rsanchez In the console that comes up when I do right click > Inspect in the popup.

Comment: @hamism I would be surprised if putting a 500 lines SDK in the background.js is common practice to solve those issues.

Comment: Yes, the problem comes from the `$.getScript` call. Why are you trying to load `firebase.js` that way if you already included it with a `<script>` tag?

Comment: And for the background page, you can do: `"scripts": ["firebase.js", "background.js"],`

Comment: Ok that seems to do the trick. The reason why I put the $.get and wanted to include firebase.js that way is because it wasn't included in there before just with the popup src tag. the manifest seems to solve this. Thanks! @rsanchez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from

```
$.getScript('firebase.js', function() { ...
```

jQuery's `getScript` will fetch the code in the file and then create a `<script>` element with the code as its text. That would be an inline script that is forbidden by the Content Security Policy.

If you want to include a file just before your code in `background.js` you can simply put:

```
"scripts": ["firebase.js", "background.js"],
```

in your manifest.json.